# How to transform this data in JS

Tags: javascript

```
X = Object {A: 33, B: 76, C: 1741}

Y = { 0:Object name: A value: 33 1:Object name: A value: 76 2:Object name: C value: 1741 }
```

like above, how to transform one object on multiple objects in JS ? X to Y.

Answer (score 3):

```
var X = {A: 33, B: 76, C: 1741};
var Y = [];    
for (key in X) {
    Y.push({name: key, value: X[key]});
}
```

Comment: This is indefinitely the cleanest answer you can ever get, 100% spot on and quite clear, only thing missing is *what* the *code* actually *does* in this situation but nevertheless very nice!